# What is the documents legalization process for Dubai work visa in India?

Tags: paperwork

I want to get my documents legalized for a Dubai work visa in India. However, I don't know the exact procedure to legalize the documents for it in India and How do I get my documents attested for it?

Comment: This would be a better question for [expatriates.se].